# How to get subdocument without root document?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this json file

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "name": "sanggiyo",
  "gender": "Male",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "tono",
      "gender": "Male",
      "children": [],
      "_id": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "rin",
      "gender": "Female",
      "children": [],
      "_id": "3"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2022-04-17T11:14:00.648Z",
  "updatedAt": "2022-04-17T11:14:16.277Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

I want to get children._id using

```
  Person.find( {$or: [ { "_id" : id }, { "children._id" : ObjectId(id) } ]} )
```

if I use id of 1, I should get all document.
but if I use id of 2, I should only get that children object without id 1, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing with aggregation framework, but much more readable and maintainable way to do that is in the code after the mongo query returned
similar to that:

```
const persons = await Person.find({$or: [ { "_id" : id }, { "children._id" : ObjectId(id) } ]});

const result = persons.flatMap(p => [p, ...p.children]).find(p => p._id === id);
```

Comment: I got undefined in result, I check console.log(persons) it have value, did it didnt have value because p._id can't found the exact match of id?
I check p._id have the exact same value but why it didnt match ._.
after I check typeof p._id and id, both of them have type object,
then after I replace === with ==, it work, thanks